# How to zoom the chrome Browser to 67% and click on the next button.?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Kindly help me to know about the correct code in Selenium where i can set the 67% zoom in chrome browser and then click on the next button.!

Comment: Why do you need to zoom? you can resize the browser or you can work on the emulator ?

Comment: Just know that Selenium does not work well when the browser is zoomed.

Answer (score 3):

Use below sample code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '0.67'");  // 67% Zoom

System.out.println("67% zoom done");

Thread.sleep(5000);

executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '1.00'"); // 100% Zoom

System.out.println("100% zoom done");
```

As stated in comment `0.67` means `67%` , `1.00` means `100%` zoom and so on